# Контент номер в блоке

Tags: html, css, img

Сижу битый час, не понимаю почему номер который создается в a::after не отображается там где нужно.
(в левом верхнем углу с изображением)
открытые css это там где вероятнее всего ошибка.
[image: В чем проблема]

Comment: a {position: relative} потерял. Без него, блок с absolute, считает родителем ближайшего, у кого есть position: relative.

Comment: дополню ответ @VladykoD -  "считает родителем ближайшего, у кого position: relative;" а так же absolute, fixed, sticky, но не static)